# Entropy and heat death

Tags: entropy

If elements or particles(can a single particle have temperature) ... have different thermal capacities how can we determine the heath death and why is it identical for everything ?

Answer (score 2):

The modern concept of heat death is when everything is in thermal equilibrium. That might well include objects with very different heat capacities and different amount of energy in them, but they will at this point have reached the same temperature.